# Symbolic diff in matlab should return vector

Tags: matlab

If I have a symbolic function `p(r,s) = r^3` in MATLAB, I obtain the derivatives `dp/dr = 3r^2` and `dp/ds = 0`, but my goal is to use `matlabFunction` to convert these expressions to function handles, with vector inputs `(r,s)`. I want something similar to `zeros(size(s))`, for the  derivative `dp/ds` so I don't obtain a scalar output if my input `(r,s)` is a vector.

This code I tried:

```
syms r s 
p = r^3
dpds = diff(p,s)
```

gives a scalar zero not variable size zero, i.e scalar output if we have vector input.

Comment: Where's your actual code for this?  You shouldn't be getting zeroes for `dp/ds`.

Comment: Diff(p,s) is scalar zero, not variable size zero.

Comment: I repeat.  Where's your actual code for this?

Answer (score 2):

This is the nature of how `matlabFunction` works.  If you provide an equation that has no independent variables as part of the equation, it will default to giving you an anonymous function with no inputs and give you a scalar result.

For example:

```
>> syms r s;
>> p = r^3;
>> dpds = diff(p,s);
>> dpdsFunc = matlabFunction(dpds)

dpdsFunc = 

    @()0.0
```

This will only give you a single scalar value each time.  This also applies to any scalar function that gives a non-zero output.  If you'd like to override this behaviour and give a variable length of this scalar that is dependent on the length of the input, you can first detect if there are any input variables in the function by checking how many variables there are.  You can use [`symvar`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/symvar.html) for that.  You would check if this array has a length of 0, and if it does, you override the function.

Something like this comes to mind:

```
syms r s;
p = r^3;
dpds = diff(p,s);

if numel(symvar(dpds)) == 0
    dpdsFunc = @(s) ones(size(s))*double(dpds); %// Thanks Daniel!
else
    dpdsFunc = matlabFunction(dpds);
end
```

This should achieve what you want.

## Minor Note

I actually think this variable length of zeroes business is something that should be put into MATLAB by default, rather than defaulting to a single value. It makes vectorizing code a lot easier.  I'm tempted to submit a feature request to MathWorks in the future.

Comment: Use `dpdsFunc = @(s) ones(size(s))*double(dpds);` to support other constants than 0 as well, besides this exactly what I was about to write.

Comment: @Daniel Oh that's a great idea.  Thanks very much.  Also, sorry for being faster! :( lol.